# how to configure doctrine command line tools on zenframework 2

Tags: command-line, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

i am using doctrine 2 on zendframework 2. i have configured both correcly and they are both working.

i however wish to use **doctrine's command line tool** to generate entities etc.

i have followed doctrine's instructions and created a cli-config.php page in the root of my application: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

i am however lost on two issues; 
the configuration requires a **bootstrap php page**; however, zendframework 2 does not use a bootstrap page; so what would the equivalent be?

Secondly, it requires us to obtain an entity mangager; would the method below be the correct way to get the entity manager:

```
public function getEntityManager()
    {
        if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->em;
    }
```

**below is how the cli-config.php page should look;**

```
// cli-config.php
require_once 'my_bootstrap.php';

// Any way to access the EntityManager from  your application
$em = GetMyEntityManager();

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));
```

i would really appreciate any help or advice on this matter.

warm regards

Andreea

**the matter has been resolved:!!**

it did not work because i was using a [cygdrive command line](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html). however, when i switched to git bash it worked perfectly. with git bash i have to use the command:

```
C: > cd project-directory
project-dir > vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have started your project using the [Zend Skeleton Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html) you do have a composer.json file. You just need to include the DoctrineORMModule [(instructions here)](http://samminds.com/2012/07/install-doctrine-2-for-zend-framework-2/)

Then, using the CMD just type

> **C: >** cd project-directory
>   **project-dir >** vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:validate-schema

There you go.

Comment: hello KeyneOn. i tried it but got this message|: $ vendor\bin\doctrine-module orm:validate-schema
-bash: vendorbindoctrine-module: command not found

Comment: check if the directory vendor\bin\doctrine-module exists in your project. If not, you need to run composer update

Comment: hi keyne. it does indeed exist. there is a file called doctrine-module in my bin folder.

Comment: Then you should be able to execute via command line vendor\bin\doctrine-module

Answer (score 2):

Once you have set up doctrine2 and zf2, you should be able to simply run all CLI commands.

```
php public/index.php orm:generate-entities
```

Using the parameters as described in [the official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#entity-generation).

**Note:** `DoctrineModule` and `DoctrineORMModule` need to be enabled within your `application.config.php`

Comment: Hello Sam. great to see you again. i tried what you said but got this message:  Could not open input file: index.php  . is  its possible that i have not configured my environment correctly. i mean, have i failed to do somthing correctly?

Comment: well, you'd need to run this command from within the `/public` directory of your application ;) Note that `DoctrineORMModule` and `DoctrineModule` need to be loaded within your `application.config.php`

Comment: thanks sam. its resolved. the problem was that i was using the command line interface cygdrive. http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html. when i switched to git bash it started to work. thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` with your Composer dependency manager. To do that, `cd` to your web site's top-level directory and type the following command:

`php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module *`

After executing this command, the `DoctrineModule` and `DoctrineOrmModule` will be installed into your `vendor` folder, and Doctrine commands will become available.

For more information about `DoctrineOrmModule`, see this:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule

Comment: hi . i added the doctrine-orm-module. however, i am not clear about the part of the instructions where it says:create directory data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy and make sure your application has write access to it. where should this directory be created, i.e is it a seperate module?