# Doctrine Orm Tools via Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In order to use the Doctrine Module ORM tools for a Zend 2 project, I need to run the command via Zend so that the bootstrapping options defined in index.php and application.config.php are correctly established.

The sum off these definitions enable a config file to be loaded which contains DB settings I wish to inject into Doctrine. This is achieved via a custom DBALConnectionFactory.

The doctrine configuration in my application.config.php is like this:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'entity_path' => array (
        __DIR__ . '../src/Application/Entity'
    ),
    'driver' => array(
        'ApplicationDriver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                'Application\Entity' => 'ApplicationDriver'
            )
        )
    ),
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'DoctrineTypeMappings' => array(
                'enum' => "string"
            )
        )
    )
),
'doctrine_factories' => array(
    'connection' => 'Application\ORM\DBALConnectionFactory',
 ),
```

According to Sam in [how to configure doctrine command line tools on zenframework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523766/how-to-configure-doctrine-command-line-tools-on-zenframework-2), I should be able to use

```
php public/index.php orm:schema-tool:create
```

but all that does for me is to lists the commands available (that suggests that the parameters are not being mapped correctly).

[image: Doctrine List]

I have also tried (from the project root) the following commands to no avail:

```
php public/index.php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
php public/index.php doctrine orm orm:schema-tool:create
```

Has anyone had any luck using the Doctrine Tools via Zend? All responses gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a custom console route interfering with the parameters for the standard route. I have amended it to pass all requests made via public/index.php straight to the standard router.

```
public function match(Request $request)
{
    // Get command line arguments and present working directory from
    // server superglobal:
    $filename = $request->getScriptName();

    if ("public/index.php" === $filename) {
        return parent::match($request);
    }

    // WARNING: cwd is $APPLICATION_HOME, so that throws off realpath!
    //
    // Convert base filename (minus .php extension and underscores) and
    // containing directory name into action and controller, respectively:
    $base = basename($filename, ".php");
    $actionName = str_replace('_', '', $base);

    $dir = dirname($filename);
    //invoked in directory e.g. $base=util/ping.php
    $level1 = basename(dirname($filename));
    // re-orient relative to APPLICATION_HOME
    $path   = $level1 . '/' . basename($filename);
    $controller = basename($dir);

    $routeMatch = new RouteMatch(
        array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $actionName), 1
    );

    // Override standard routing:
    $routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('default');
    return $routeMatch;
}
```